# TYPO3 7.6 get youtube-url from youtube-media-file for custom content element with fancybox

Tags: video, youtube, typo3, fancybox, typo3-7.6.x

if someone has a better title for my problem, go ahead and change it... ;-)

I've been googling for quite a while but either I don't ask the right question or noone had struggles with this so far.

I'm working with TYPO3 7.6, fancyBox v3.0.47 (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and my own content element which I created for an image-gallery. So far so good. Everything worked fine until the customer asked to add video files to that gallery. The gallery uses fancyBox for the lightbox and I use it as follows:

```
<div class="imgGalleryIMG">
  <a href="/fileadmin{file.originalFile.identifier}" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="{file.description}">
    <f:image image="{file}" crop="{file.crop}" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The link is needed for the fancybox and the image inside is the previewed image (that can be cropped).

This works fine with images and I can change `<f:image image="{file}"` to `<f:media file="{file}" />` so that the youtube video which is loaded into the content element with "Add media from URL" is displayed and starts playing when clicking on it but this way the lightbox from fancyBox won't popup and it stays as small as the preview-image.

I tried using a different approach and I got stuck with the youtube video. By using "Add media from URL" the video is being saved to the filelist as youtube-file (meaning it has the file-extension ".youtube") and it's title becomes the name of the file. When I use `<f:debug>` I can't find the real link (eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEkSYw3o5is) nor the video id (eg. WEkSYw3o5is) to the youtube video. If I use the above approach that I use for the images, I have a preview-image of the video but when I click on it the lightbox opens and there's nothing else but the youtube-video-id displayed.

2nd approach:

```
<div class="imgGalleryIMG">
  <f:if condition="{file.originalFile.properties.extension} == 'youtube'">
    <f:then>
      <a href="{file.originalFile.identifier}" data-type="iframe" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="{file.description}">
        <f:image image="{file}" />
      </a>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <a href="/fileadmin{file.originalFile.identifier}" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="{file.description}">
        <f:image image="{file}" crop="{file.crop}" />
      </a>
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
</div>
```

If I'm correct what I need is the link to the youtube video for the link for fancybox as stated in it's documentation.

What I really want is a display-image for the youtube-video, which on click will be revealed in the lightbox (without autoplay). How can I achieve this?

I would favour a solution that works changing the template only.

**EDIT**

With the first approach after rendering and fancybox doing its magic the result looks as follows:

```
<div class="fancybox-container fancybox-show-controls fancybox-show-infobar fancybox-show-buttons fancybox-container--ready fancybox-controls--canzoomIn" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="fancybox-container-1" style="">
  ...
  <div class="fancybox-slider-wrap">
    <div class="fancybox-slider" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
      <div class="fancybox-slide fancybox-slide--current fancybox-slide--image fancybox-slide--complete" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
        <div class="fancybox-placeholder" style="transform: translate(512px, 131px) scale(1, 1); width: 1024px; height: 767.94px; opacity: 1; transition: none;">
          <img class="fancybox-image" src="/fileadmin/user_upload/pathToImg.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ...
  </div>
... 
</div>
```

This is the lightbox code. The image-src is being taken from the link around the image in my first approach (not from the image-file). This is why I would like to get the youtube-url or the youtube-id into my partial with fluid.

---

***SOLUTION***

Thanks to minifranske I found an easy way to do it:

```
<f:if condition="{file.originalFile.properties.extension} == 'youtube'">
  <f:then>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{file.contents}" data-type="iframe" 
data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="{file.description}">
      <f:image image="{file}" />
    </a>
  </f:then>
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the URL: `{file.publicUrl}`
To get the YouTube id: `{file.contents}`

Comment: You're the best!! Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for hours.THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

First I want to explain what exactly will happen, if a YouTube video is added to the TYPO3 media list. TYPO3 will store the video ID and only the video ID in the `.youtube` file it creates. It will use this video ID in a renderer that adds an iFrame and the URL to this id. All that happens in the `f:media` ViewHelper. The according renderer is located at `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Rendering\YouTubeRenderer`.
Now, what you are trying to achive isn't possible without a little efford imo.
You need to add an additional image field for the thumbnail, so you can do something like this for example:

```
<f:if condition="{youtubeFile}">
    <div class="yt-facybox">
        <a class="facybox" href="#yt-iframe">
            <f:media file="{youtubeThumbnailFile}" />
        </a>
        <div style="display: none" id="yt-iframe">
            <f:media file="{youtubeFile}" width="600" height="530" />
        </div>
    </div>
</f:if>
```

This way your fancybox will just open the hidden iFrame container. The width and height of the iFrame can be adjusted by the width and height attributes for the ViewHelper.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the youtube video. Actually if your information about the youtube-file is true, isn't there a way to get that value/video ID standing in this file into the href? If I'm not completely wrong, fancyBox uses the href to display the image / video in the lightbox... Otherwise my first approach wouldn't be working correctly and it does. If possible I would like to make it as simple as possible. The partial is already complicated and too lenghty (including loops and ifs). Thanks for your help so far. :-)

Comment: I've added some additional information in my original question (see EDIT)

Comment: "You need to add an additional image field for the thumbnail, so you can do something like this for ..." This is not totally true. If you use  `<f:image image="{file}" />` for a YouTube or Vimeo file it will render an image for you.

Comment: @minifranske Yeah, I didn't know that the ImageViewHelper can even render an image out of a video resource. Still don't know if this also works for non Vimeo/YouTube sources, though.

Comment: That will not work out if the box for other video files. The core ships a helper class for YouTube and Vimeo that fetches the image from the YouTube or Vimeo API.